# Scheduled SQL job doesn't start

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with SQL Server 2008 jobs. Jobs are scheduled and run successful, but occassionaly occurs, that a time job doesn't start. No errors in log. No job history. When I disable and enable job again, it runs in scheduled time.

Where is the problem?

Comment: No idea - not enough information to tell.  There must be a log somewhere that gives some information; you just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your SQL server to latest version(all hotfixes), there was some bugs with jobs which was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an agent conflict with other systems resources.
Try changing the job start time, if possible.